# Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest' [...] is not a valid HTTP header field value

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, rest, post

I am developing an application with AngularJS (client side) and Java (server side) using RESTful services (with Jersey).

In the client I have something like this

```
$http({
        url : "/Something/rest/...",
        method : "POST",
        headers : {
            ...
            'text' : text
        }
    });
```

on the server side my Java method header looks like this

```
 public JSONObject myMethod(@HeaderParam("text") String text [...]) throws JSONException
```

And I'm getting this error when trying to send a request

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Some text here formatted with \n and \t' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

Is this because of the formatting? Is it because the text is quite long?

What should I change? Please guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sending your 'text' in headers on purpose? This is in general not a place for doing this.
For sending content through POST(or GET) you should use 'data' field.
So:

```
$http({
    url : "/Something/rest/...",
    method : "POST",
    data: {
        ...
        'text' : text
    }
});
```

,and on the server side similar change for getting your data from POST. 
You don't need and shouldn't mess with headers unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: If one is using a 3rd party library (such as Restangular) where we do not have control over this, how do we avoid 'not a valid HTTP header field value' when using the formatting OP described?

Answer (score 7):

I had faced this problem. Please make sure that in your code header name doesn't contain space. i.e. 'designId ' is invalid, as it contain space at end

Comment: This is what my problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this a few days back. I simply clear my cookies and other site data and it was able to resolve the issue.